# Prove $xyz\left[x+y+z+\frac{3}{2}\right]\le\frac{3}{8}$ for $\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{y+1}+\frac{1}{z+1}=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Prove that for all positive reals $x,y,z$ with the property $\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{y+1}+\frac{1}{z+1}=2$,
> $$xyz\left[x+y+z+\frac{3}{2}\right]\le\frac{3}{8}.$$

This inequality arose as a reduction of a more complicated olympiad inequality with surds in it.
Honestly I have no clue how to prove this inequality. After eliminating $z$ using the given condition and clearing denominators, I found using computer algebra that the inequality is equivalent to proving $$3\left(x^2+y^2\right)+8x^2y^2+32x^3y^3+16x^3y^3\left(x+y\right)-2xy-8xy\left(x^2+y^2\right)-12x^2y^2-4x^2y^2\left(x+y\right)\ge0,$$

which I can't seem to rearrange into a "sum of non-negatives" format to prove that $x=y=z=\frac{1}{2}$, which is where the equality case seems to lie.

Hints or solution would be appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Hint: You may use pqr method.